# How to keep only specific punctuation mark in a column

Tags: r, regex

In the column text how it is possible to remove all punctuation remarks but keep only the ?

```
data.frame(id = c(1), text = c("keep<>-??it--!@#"))
```

expected output

```
data.frame(id = c(1), text = c("keep??it"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution would be to used nested `gsub` commands that converts `?` to a particular unusual string (like "foobar"), gets rid of all punctuation, then writes "foobar" back to `?`:

```r
gsub("foobar", "?", gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", gsub("\\?", "foobar", df$text)))
#> [1] "keep??it"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gsub` you could do:

```
gsub("(\\?+)|[[:punct:]]","\\1",df$text)

[1] "keep??it"
```

Answer (score 0):

`gsub('[[:punct:] ]+',' ',data)` removes **all** punctuation which is not what you want.

But this is:

```
library(stringr)
sapply(df, function(x) str_replace_all(x, "<|>|-|!|@|#",""))
     id  text      
[1,] "1" "a"       
[2,] "2" "keep??it"
```

Better IMO than other answers because no need for nesting, and lets you define whichever characters to `sub`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using negative lookahead:

```
gsub("(?!\\?)[[:punct:]]", "", df$text, perl = T)
[1] "keep??it"
```

The negative lookahead asserts that the next character is **not** a `?` and then matches any punctuation.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1), text = c("keep<>-??it--!@#"))
```